# Cannot run program CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, debugging, maven-plugin

I get the titled error when I use jvmarguments in the pom file. I'm using mvnw command with the below plugin to enable debugging. If I remove the jvm argument, it works. But I want to enable remote debugging with the mvnw command

**Code Snippet:**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            <executable>true</executable>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments> 
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Error:**

> *[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.7.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project dxcgateway: Could not exec java: Cannot run
>   program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\bin\java.exe":
>   CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long ->
>   [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
>   Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.7.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project dxcg ateway: Could not exec java
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206,
>   The filename or extension is too long
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.RunProcess.run (RunProcess.java:77)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206,
>   The filename or extension is too long
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.RunProcess.run (RunProcess.java:77)*

Comment: [Forking](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#fork) is enabled by default since Spring Boot 2.2. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125404/since-2-2-0-spring-boot-maven-plugin-create-2-java-process-may-cause-createproc question and solution

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I used the below commandand it worked. 
   mvnw -Dmaven.repo.local=C:/mavenRepo

Answer (score 15):

For me I had the similar exception, below change solved the issue

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>false</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Awesome, the error is really doesn't point easily to that.

Comment: unfortunately this parameter is marked for deprectation in spring boot v3. Need another solution

Answer (score 7):

change

```
<fork>true</fork>
```

to

```
<fork>false</fork>
```

Comment: unfortunately this parameter is marked for deprectation in spring boot v3. Need another solution

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by a Windows OS limitation. To solve it:

1. Move `.m2` repository to `c:\`
2. Open `settings.xml` from `%MAVEN_HOME%/conf` and look for `\<settings>.\<localRepository>`(uncomment it if its commented out already) and change its value to `c:/.m2/repository`
3. Save the file and run the build again

Answer (score 6):

If you are using IntelliJ Idea platform just change the launch configuration to avoid using the default shorten line

[image]

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I dont use intellij, by the way

Comment: This worked for me for intellij